# Can't read ciphertext from file using RSA encryption using crypto++

Tags: c++, encryption

I'm creating a program in C++ that uses crypto++ to do RSA encryption. I have to input a string from the user, encrypt it, write it a file and then read it from the file and decrypt it.When I use the cipher text directly without reading from the file it works but when I use the string from the file, it breaks.Any ideas on the reason why this happening? Here's the code

```
std::string plain, getText, cipher, decrypted_data;

cout << "Enter the plain text :\n";//getting the string from the user;
getline(std::cin, plain);

std::cout << "Plain Text: " << plain << std::endl;//printing the plain text
std::cout << std::endl;

CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool rng;


// Encryption & Decryption
CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction params;
params.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rng, 1536);


CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey privateKey(params);
CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey publicKey(params);

CryptoPP::RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor e(publicKey);
CryptoPP::StringSource(plain, true, new CryptoPP::PK_EncryptorFilter(rng, e, new CryptoPP::StringSink(cipher)));

cout << "Ciphertext: " << cipher << endl;
std::ofstream out("output.text");//writing to a file
out << cipher;
out.close();
cout << endl;



std::ifstream readfile("output.text");//reading from the file
if (readfile.is_open())
{
    while (getline(readfile, getText))
    {

        std::cout << getText << '\n';
    }
}       
    readfile.close();


CryptoPP::RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor d(privateKey);
CryptoPP::StringSource(getText, true, new CryptoPP::PK_DecryptorFilter(rng, d, new CryptoPP::StringSink(decrypted_data)));


std::cout << "Decrypted Text: " << decrypted_data << std::endl;//printing the decrypted file
```

Comment: A ciphertext is not representable as a text string, so that's probably it.

Comment: When I did a similar program using AES encryption, it worked. How else can I do this?